# Keeping session when switching from different ports

Tags: php, tornado

I have a member's area on my website on my default port 80, there is a user app running on port 8080 of my website called UserPort, when a user goes to UserPort a new empty(has no username inside) session is created. Is there anyway for me to keep the same session from port 80 onto port 8080?

**EDIT: Ok so I was referred to the following answer for my problem=[Same Session ID on Same IP Address but Different Ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412864/same-session-id-on-same-ip-address-but-different-ports/21773261#21773261) but the code isn't explained well, do I put the first segment of the code with port 110 into my member's area page and put the second segment into my UserPort page?**

Comment: And are you starting a session on your UserPort page?

Comment: Yes I am with that code: `session_start(); `

Comment: Are the apps (on port 80 e 8080) running on the same server? What is the application server?

Comment: No. Apache is running on port 80 and Tornado on port 8080.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21773261/1292359

Comment: I saw that but I didnt really get what I have to do.

Comment: Ok so I was referred to the following answer for my problem= http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412864/same-session-id-on-same-ip-address-but-different-ports/21773261#21773261 but the code isn't explained well, do I put the first segment of the code with port 110 into my member's area page and put the second segment into my UserPort page?

Answer (score -1):

Because there are two different servers, you cannot easily (as in out-of-the-box) share the session. However, you could make a request from your apache app to your tornado app to "prepare" a session for the user. Then, when the user is redirected to the UserPort, she should get something to identify herself. Because of this: [Are HTTP cookies port specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific) it's not reliable to use cookies, so a one-off token in the URL would probably do.

To put it into a very simplified pseude code:

```
// apache 
$token = createRandomString();
call($tornadoAppUrl, $userData, $token);
$link = createUserPortLink($tornadoAppUrl, $token);
echo "<a href='$link'>go to UserPort</a>"

//tornado UserPort
$token = 
$userData = getUserSession($token);
... act accordingly
```

Hope it's clear.